# Does this integral converge? $\int_2^\infty \frac{x \sin^2 x}{x^3-1}\ \mathsf dx$

Tags: convergence-divergence, improper-integrals

Does $$\int_2^\infty \frac{x \sin^2 x}{x^3-1} dx$$ converge or diverge?
I think this is a comparison test but I'm not sure what integral I should compare it with.
Thanks

Comment: The function blows up badly at $1$. Divergence.

Comment: WA confirms this: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+%28xsin%5E2x%29%2F%28x%5E3-1%29+from+1+to+infinity

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit:** The integral used to be from $1$ to $\infty$, now it is from $2$ to $\infty$. So the badness of our function has become irrelevant.

If $x\ge 2$, then the top is positive and $\le x$, and the bottom is greater than $x^3/2$. So our function is less than $\frac{2}{x^2}$. Since $\int_2^\infty \frac{2}{x^2}\,dx$ converges, so does our integral.

**Old answer:** Note that $x^3-1=(x-1)(x^2+x+1)$. If $x$ is reasonably near to $1$ but greater than $1$, our function is greater than
$$\frac{\sin^2(1)}{4(x-1)}.$$
But $\int_1^{1+\delta}\frac{dx}{x-1}$ diverges for any positive $\delta$, so our integral diverges.